# Cauchy-Riemann equations and required continuity of derivatives

Tags: complex-analysis, examples-counterexamples, analyticity, cauchy-riemann-equations

So I just read, that for any analytic function, the Cauchy-Riemann equations will hold. However, the reverse, i.e. Cauchy-Riemann equations hold -> function is analytic, is supposedly only true if the partial derivatives are continuous.

What would be an example though? I cannot think of any function, where the Cauchy-Riemann equations would hold, while not being analytic.

Can someone please help me out?

Comment: $f(z)=z^5/|z|^4$ if $z\ne0$ and $0$ if $z=0$

Comment: In this example, C-R only holds at 0, right? For a general z = x + iy, C-R seem to not hold unless I miscalculated.

Answer (score 1):

Take any analytic function defined on $\mathbb C$. Now remove all the parts except those which are on the coordinate axes, so only a kind of cross remains. Replace the removed parts by some horribly discontinuous mess, such that the new function is also discontinuous at $0$. The function obtained this way will still be partially differentiable at $0$, and the partial derivatives will still be the same as those of the original function, since the partial derivatives at $0$ only depend on how the function behaves on the coordinate axis, which we didn't change.

A concrete example:

$$f(z)=\begin{cases}0&z\textrm{ is on the coordinate axes}\\0&z\textrm{ has both rational imaginary and real part}\\1&\textrm{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Comment: So just to clarify, your specific example would be nowhere analytic, but C-R hold at 0, am I right? Cauchy-Riemann eq. hold only at 0, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.